# Unix tail script with grep

Tags: unix

Can you help me with a shell script, which tail on live every new file in folder and reads lines in the file that coming and grep specific lines and write it to the file. For example:
Find latest file in folder 
then unix read it like `cat` command that newest file, then grep it out specific lines like `grep -A3 "some word"` and those lines will be saved in file like `>>someother file`.

Answer (score 0):

To detect file-system changes, you might want to have a look at inotify.